# Ember app blank page on Firefox OS

Tags: ember.js, firefox-os

I was following [this guide](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Apps/Quickstart) on MDN for developing a Firefox OS App using Ember. It runs without problems in the browser but when I try to install it on Firefox OS using the Firefox WebIDE I just get a blank page.

The console output shows no errors but every time I try to install it on Firefox OS the ember console displays `Content Security Policy violation: {}`

I have tried it on my Geeksphone Revolution running Firefox OS 2.0 and the Firefox OS simulator for 1.4 and 2.0.

System info:

- OS: OS X 10.10.3
- Ember version: 0.2.6
- Node version: 0.12.0

Comment: I have never deployed to Firefox OS, but I would guess that it is very similar to what you do with Cordova apps. With those you have to delete `baseURL` and change `locationType` to none. See: http://givan.se/ember-cli-phonegap/

Comment: @Eschon Have a look here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/CSP . It's not very clear from your question why you're having issues. CSP violation might happen for multiple reasons such as using eval somewhere or using scripts in scripts tag instead of files...

If you can show more of your code, we might be able to figure out what's going on.

Comment: @LoïcFaure-Lacroix it should be exactly the code that can be found at https://github.com/brittanystoroz/its-five-o-clock-somewhere. But for now I have found a workaround and I will answer my own question now.

Answer (score 0):

I think I did the whole installing wrong. I used Open hosted app from the WebIDE and just entered my IP Address. Looking at [this article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Marketplace/Options/Self_publishing#Self-publishing_packaged_apps) on MDN I found out that I need a page with a script to correctly install my app.

For now I found a workaround by using `Open Packaged App` on my `dist` directory.